# Letsencrypt + Docker - the best way to handle symlink?

Tags: linux, docker, nginx, lets-encrypt

I have a Nginx server running on `Docker` on a Ubuntu host and I wanted to integrate `Letsencrypt` certificates on it. As I had the `Nginx` image already created with all the conf setup, after reading different articles I decided to install Letsencrypt on the host and mount the `/etc/letsencrypt/` folder in a shared volume in the `Nginx` container. The problem I had is that symlinks belongs to the file system itself and cannot be resolved by the container which makes sense.

My question is then: what would be the best way to approach this: Should I add all the `Letsencrypt` setup inside my `Nginx` custom Dockerfile to get it up and running? Is it possible though to create a separate container which only has `Letsencrypt` and share a volume from there? Or is it possible somehow to resolve this via changes on my current solution?

Note that at the moment I'm creating a copy of the certificates and pasting them into the volume which is fine but I want to automate the renewal (using `certbot renew --dry-run` ).

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: don't understand the negative rating. I'm not looking for a detailed solution but the pattern to follow

Comment: no need to install SSL service in docker,only used old generated certificates and copy it into container by dockerfile. and other option is bind run time as https://medium.com/@mvuksano/using-tls-certificates-with-nginx-docker-container-74c6769a26db

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of running let's encrypt on the host, you should do everything inside Docker. And the best  is there is already a solution for that: https://hub.docker.com/r/nginxproxy/acme-companion

This enables the proxy to automatically obtain and renew certificates.

Comment: This repo is not maintained anymore...

Comment: @gradosevic Thanks for the comment. It has been replaced by another repo. Will change the link in my answer.

Answer (score 14):

The symlinks within the letsencrypt folder will resolve within a docker container as long as the entire `/etc/letsencrypt` directory is mounted as the volume. Or rather, as long as both the `live` and `archive` directory for the site of interest are mounted. What I mean is, one of the symlinks for a letsencrypt domain cert looks like this:

`/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/cert.pem --> ../../archive/example.com/cert1.pem`

To be able to reference the "live" cert name from within my docker container, I created the following volume mounting the whole letsencrypt etc directory:

`-v /etc/letsencrypt:/certs`

Since the full `/etc/letsencrypt` is mounted, the volume gets *both* `live` and *also* `archive`, so the symlink of `../../archive` resolves as long as I'm referencing the absolute path to the file I want. In my server config file:

`certfile /certs/live/example.com/cert.pem`

This works!

Now the really ugly part of this is that I just made *all* of my letsencrypt certs available to just this one container. But it works for my use case right now where I only have one domain I'm using letsencrypt for on this server. I have used letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion before and I prefer that by far, when I can do it.

Edit: Thought of a way to *only* share the certs needed for the site. Two volume entries:

- `/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com:/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com`
- `/etc/letsencrypt/archive/example.com:/etc/letsencrypt/archive/example.com`